# Visual Studio 15 Community edition not referencing "system.io.packaging"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have seen numerous post relating to this which suggest all you need to do is ensure your project references windowsbase.dll. I checked and the project "Open-xml-PowerTools" does indeed reference it. So any idea on what I am missing? The solution is from https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Quote: "It is based on, and extends the functionality of the Open XML SDK".  Which is what you not have installed, System.IO.Packaging comes from that SDK.  Follow the link.

Comment: I have installed OPEN XML SDK.  The solution builds without error and all the test complete without error.

Comment: I discovered the system.io.packaging.dll in my nugets folder. C:\Users\myusername\.nuget\packages\System.IO.Packaging\4.3.0\ref\net46 adding this to the C:\Users\Stuart\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Open-XML-SDK\DocumentFormat.OpenXml\bin\Debug directory allowed open-xml-powertools to build.

Comment: I had looked at the post in the link but none of the ideas suggested work for me. [link](http://ericwhite.com/blog/forums/topic/problem-building-open-xml-sdk/)